# How to control progress bar during executing async operations

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, async-await, progress-bar

during implementing exporting util for my project I encounter a problem with blocking UI during uploading files. Basically the problem is that during async task I'm not able to update progress bar.

I already tried a couple of solutions. In general when i call exportPopUp.ShowDialog() it blocks the execution of copyAttachment() and the whole logic is done after closing form. I decided to use Show() but when i does that the form is not alive (all grey)

Here is my background logic:

```
   private void exportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // get files
        int row = reportsDataGrid.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
        if (row >= 0)
        {
            string problemId = reportsDataGrid.Rows[row].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            AC.Trace.I("Problem Id", problemId);
            FolderBrowserDialog dlgFolderBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            dlgFolderBrowser.Description = "Select folder to save Report files!";
            DialogResult result = dlgFolderBrowser.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string folderName = dlgFolderBrowser.SelectedPath;
                AC.Trace.I("Destination folder name", folderName);
                CIS.PRS.Data.Attachments attachments = jampPrsService.ReportFiles(problemId);
                processAttachments(attachments, folderName, problemId);
            }
        }
    }

    private async void processAttachments(Attachments attachments, string folderName, string problemId)
    {
        this.exportPath = folderName + "\\" + problemId;
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        this.exportPopUp = new exportPopUp(attachments.Size(), cts);
        this.exportPopUp.ExportFinished += ExportPopUp_ExportFinished;
        exportPopUp.setExportLabelText("Exporting problem report " + problemId);
        exportPopUp.ShowDialog();
        await copyAttachments(attachments, folderName, problemId);
    }

    private void ExportPopUp_ExportFinished()
    {
        this.finishExport();
    }

    private async Task copyAttachments(Attachments attachments, string folderName, string problemId)
    {
        //List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (Attachment attachment in attachments.attachments)
        {
            //tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => copy(attachment, folderName, problemId)));
            await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => copy(attachment, folderName, problemId));
        }
        //await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    private void copy(Attachment attachment, string folderName, string problemId)
    {
        FileStream fs = null;
        if (!Directory.Exists(exportPath))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(exportPath);
        }
        try
        {
            using (fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(exportPath, attachment.Name), FileMode.Create))
            {
                fs.WriteAsync(attachment.Data, 0, attachment.Data.Length, this.cts.Token).Wait();
                fs.Flush();
                fs.Close();
                this.exportPopUp.performProgressBarStep();
            }
            AC.Trace.I("File has been saved: ", attachment.Name);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            AC.Trace.E("Cannot write file " + attachment.Name, ex);
        }
    }
    private void finishExport()
    {
        this.exportPopUp.Close();
        this.exportPopUp.Dispose();
        MessageBoxCc.ShowInformation("Problem report exported succesfully. \n" +
                "Report exported to '"+ exportPath + "'", "Problem Request", "675");
    }
}
```

Here is my exportPopUp class:

```
public delegate void ExportFinishHandler();

    public partial class exportPopUp : Form
    {
        public event ExportFinishHandler ExportFinished;

        private CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource;

        public exportPopUp(int progressBarSize, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.CenterToScreen();
            this.cancellationTokenSource = cancellationTokenSource;
            this.progressBar.Maximum = progressBarSize;
            this.progressBar.Step = 1;
            this.progressBar.Value = 0;        
        }

        public void setExportLabelText(string text)
        {
            exportLabel.Text = text;
        }

        public void performProgressBarStep()
        {
            this.progressBar.PerformStep();
            MessageBoxCc.ShowInformation("VALUE " + this.progressBar.Value + " MAX " + this.progressBar.Maximum, "KOZA", "123");
            if(this.progressBar.Value == this.progressBar.Maximum)
            {
                this.ExportFinished();
            }
        }

        private void cancelBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        }
    }
```

Generally the whole logic works as I expected, but I'm not able to do copy tasks and update progress bar at same time. Thanks in advance

UPDATE

After changes its working as expected but for calling export not form export button its grey and stock again.

Im attaching execution of this method not from export button

Listener class:

```
// Inner listener class 
public class ReportCreatedListener
{
    private frameProblemRequestReport frameProblemRequestReport;

    public ReportCreatedListener(frameProblemRequestReport frameProblemRequestReport)
    {
        this.frameProblemRequestReport = frameProblemRequestReport;
    }

    public async Task notifyRaportCreated(string problemId)
    {
        await this.frameProblemRequestReport.reportCreationFinished(problemId);
    }
}
```

The call:

```
    internal async Task reportCreationFinished(string lastProblemId)
    {
        if ((lastProblemId).Contains(report.ReportInfo.ProblemId))
        {
            string problemId = report.ReportInfo.ProblemId;
            string folderName = "C:\\Users\\Z006DQF6\\Desktop";
            AC.Trace.I("Exporting created raport to location: ", folderName);
            CIS.PRS.Data.Attachments attachments = jampPrsService.ReportFiles(lastProblemId);
            await processAttachments(attachments, folderName, problemId);
        }
    }
```

reportCreationFinished is triggered from another listener

```
    private class StateListener : CompoundStateListener
    {
        private JAMPPRSService service;
        public StateListener(JAMPPRSService service)
        {
            this.service = service;
        }
        public async void stateChanged(CompoundModel cm)
        {
            string lastSendReportId = cm.getMember("LastCreatedReportId").getValue().ToString();
            await service.reportCreatedListener.notifyRaportCreated(lastSendReportId);
        }
    }
```

I'm not able go any higher because this event is coming from backend written in java

Comment: why do you use `Wait` on your filestream? you make an async operation synchronously this way. This can lead to a deadlock.

Comment: I am aware of that ill will change it after ill get that progress bar done, because if ill use it without wait I'm not able to control which file is during copy. The final version will looks like commented lines with task and without wait at fileStream.

Comment: I still have not entirely understood your problem. " I'm not able to update progress bar." What exactly does that mean? Do you get exceptions? is the bar simply not updating?

Comment: If i use ShowDialog() the whole execution of copying files is done after closing the form, when i use Show which is not blocking the execution of the form is all grey and im getting the notificaton that operation is done, but im not able to see any progress because the whole form is grey

Comment: Sorry i didn't add most important method it is aleady updated

Comment: `async void processAttachments` async void is for events only. Otherwise it will block the UI. Usually you need to progress the async await pattern all the way up to the last handler (button click or whatever starts it).

Comment: "I decided to use Show() but when i does that the form is not alive (all grey)" which form? the `exportPopUp` or the parent form?

Comment: can you post the calling site of "processAttachments" ?

Comment: The exportPopUp is grey and the parent form is getting stock

Comment: I updated the question with proscessAttachemnt execution

Comment: Do you intend to copy all attachments in parallel? or one after the other? that is not clear to me, because you uncommented code suggest the first scenario and the actual code the second

Comment: I left parallel approach, I'm no sure which one i suppose to use i wait for supervisor to decide if we can do it in parallel

Comment: " i wait for supervisor to decide " isn't it a great position ?=! ;) I like that too.

Comment: I made an update according to you advice, but it is still not working

Comment: again same question where is the calling site of `notifyRaportCreated`? why is it `async void` ? is it an event handler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here the switching from asynchronous processing to synchronous. You do it even twice in your code.

If you start with async await, you need to draw it through the entire calling hierarchy.

1) start with the click handler. This should be the only `async void` method in the hierarchy. Await here the next one

```
private async void exportButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await processAttachments(attachments, folderName, problemId);
}
```

2) make the next called method to return a Task and use `Show` so that `copyAttachments` will be executed afterwards and can be awaited

```
          return Task here
                |
                v
private async Task processAttachments(Attachments attachments, string folderName, string problemId)
{
    this.exportPath = folderName + "\\" + problemId;
    cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    this.exportPopUp = new exportPopUp(attachments.Size(), cts);
    this.exportPopUp.ExportFinished += ExportPopUp_ExportFinished;
    exportPopUp.setExportLabelText("Exporting problem report " + problemId);
    exportPopUp.Show();  // <= !
    await copyAttachments(attachments, folderName, problemId);
}
```

3) use the Task that is returned from `fs.WriteAsync` and await it. Make the `copy` method again return a Task to propagate it upwards:

```
private void copy(Attachment attachment, string folderName, string problemId)
{
    ...
    try
    {
        using (fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(exportPath, attachment.Name), FileMode.Create))
        {
            awaitfs.WriteAsync(attachment.Data, 0, attachment.Data.Length, this.cts.Token);
            fs.Flush();
            fs.Close();
            this.exportPopUp.performProgressBarStep();
        }           
    }
    ...
```

4) await the copy method (if you want to copy the attachments one after the other):

```
private async Task copyAttachments(Attachments attachments, string folderName, string problemId)
{
    foreach (Attachment attachment in attachments.attachments)
    {            
        await copy(attachment, folderName, problemId));
    }
}
```

This should yield a working solution, in which both Forms will stay responsive and you will see the progress bar filling up.

Comment: Ok, it is working prefectly fine thank you for that, but i got another problem, if I will do the export by button click it works perferctly , but if i'm calling progressAttachments() to do the export after creation of report it looks grey again